# In C++ why can't I take the address of a function that also has a templated version?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, overload-resolution

Here is a piece of code that tries to provide a pointer to an overloaded function to another function that can accept a value of any type:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void AcceptAnything(T&&);

void Foo();

template <typename T>
void Foo();

void Bar() {
  AcceptAnything(&Foo);
}
```

This [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/xncbT74sr), giving the following error under clang:

```
<source>:10:3: error: no matching function for call to 'AcceptAnything'
   10 |   AcceptAnything(&Foo);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:2:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
    2 | void AcceptAnything(T&&);
      |      ^
```

I understand why you can't do this for an overloaded function in general. But in this particular case I'm surprised that `&Foo` doesn't have type `void(*)()`, given that no template arguments are provided. My mental model is:

- The only function named `Foo` here is the untemplated one, with the other one being a family of functions named `Foo<T>` for any type `T`.
- The expression `&Foo` refers to the address of a particular function named `Foo`.
- There is no such thing as the address of a family of functions.

So I would expect that `&Foo` unambiguously means "a pointer to the untemplated function `Foo`". But both gcc and clang disagree with me, so my mental model must be wrong.

**Why is `&Foo` ambiguous in this case, and which part of the standard covers it?**

Comment: A "function template" is not a "function" and `Foo` is the name of a template. **You can't take the address of a template**. You need to write `&Foo<int>` etc to make it work.

Comment: The answer should be in [[over.over\]](https://wg21.link/over.over), but reading that seems to imply the non-templated function should be unambiguously chosen (`T` shouldn't be deducible, so no `Foo<T>` functions should be in the overload set, but even if they were, [[over.over\]p5](https://wg21.link/over.over#5.sentence-2))

Comment: @Artyer Do note that there is no specialization that can/will be generated here. So nothing is eliminated from the set here as explained in my answer. Although if there were some case where specialization were to be generated, then also the non-template function would be used.

Comment: This is [CWG 2873](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2873.html)

Comment: Whoa. Was that filed because of my question? (Did you file it?)

Comment: @jacobsa I did file it.

Answer (score 3):

This is [CWG 2873](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2873.html) and current wording seems to make the program **well-formed** even though all compilers reject the code.

The non-template function is the only viable option here since template argument deduction fails here for function template `Foo` and the phrase *"if any"* in [over.over#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#3) seems to mean that template are ignored if deduction fails. So there is no specialization that can be added to the set and the set contains only one candidate which is the non-template function.

---

Now as there is no target from the function template `Foo`, the template argument deduction for `Foo` **fails** so no specialization will be added to set and as per [over.over#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#3) the template will be ignored:

> The specialization, **if any**, **generated by template argument deduction** ([temp.over], [temp.deduct.funcaddr], [temp.arg.explicit]) **for each function template named is added to the set of selected functions considered.**

Note the emphasis on "if any" in the above quoted reference.

Since template argument deduction fails here, there is no specialization that is added to the set. And the only candidate in the set is the non-template function which will be used.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the citation. Are you sure that overload resolution is even relevant here though? Like, where does it say that [over.over]/5 governs the type of the expression `&Foo` in the first place?

Comment: @jacobsa `Foo` is an *id-expression* which refers to an overload set here. And [over.over] describes what happens for in such case.

Comment: @jacobsa you need to take into account [temp.deduct.type] to explain why [over.over] does what it does, i.e. why the target type is not determined, and therefore the overload set still contains the template function.  I've tried to explain that in my answer.

Comment: @user12002570 over.over#5.sentence-2 would not apply because over.over#3 has already produced a failure to resolve template parmeter deduction. see [temp.deduct.funcaddr#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.funcaddr#1) and [temp.deduct.type#4 & 5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#5.6)

Comment: @wearetherobots This is [CWG 2873](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2873.html). Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not language lawyer here, but given the code snippet in the OP, the function template `Foo` doesn't undergo template argument deduction, so I think the answer is more straightforwardly contained in [over.over#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#3):

> The specialization, if any, generated by template argument deduction ([temp.over], [temp.deduct.funcaddr], [temp.arg.explicit]) for each function template named is added to the set of selected functions considered.

Because no specialization of the tempalted `Foo` has ever been produced, the set of selected functions considered truly only contains the non-templated `Foo`.

Answer (score -2):

The expression `AcceptAnything(&Foo);` attempts to do two things:

1. Deduce the parameter type for `AcceptAnything` function template,
2. Determine the address of the overloaded set `Foo`, thats is what `&Foo` refers to.

The reason why `&Foo` is not resolved to the address of the function `Foo` is because the *target* (the parameter of the function `AcceptAnaything()`) is not determined explicitly.

Because `AcceptAnything()` is a template function, the call requires determining which template instantiation it refers to.
The compiler must deduce the template parameter and it uses the value passed to the function parameter to do this.  However, the standard specifies that when this happens with a value whose type is the address of the function, and the potential candidates (a.k.a. overload set) contain function template, then the deduction fails. As the deduction fails, the parameter type cannot be used to constrain the resolution of what `&Foo` refers to.

It is circular... but that's my understanding.  More details and relevant extracts from the standard are below.

---

Note that gcc gives a more explicit error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'AcceptAnything(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

The issue is similar with a statement as `auto f = &Foo`, which cannot be resolved either, although the error message is less explicit in that case.

To give a different perspective on the issue, note that the following code compiles, because it makes (1) explicit, and therefore allows the compiler to resolve the overload set in (2):

```
AcceptAnything<void()>(&Foo);
```

The reaons why this works is similar to why the resolution can happen in the following statement: `void (*f)() = &Foo;`.

See repro: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zd6PdzsfT)

---

##### relevant extracts from standard

If (2) is done independently of (1), we would have a target type that would resolve the address of the overload set, and discard the function template named `Foo`.  See [over.over](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over):

> An id-expression whose terminal name refers to an overload set S and that appears without arguments is resolved to a function, a pointer to function, or a pointer to member function for a specific function that is chosen from a set of functions selected from S determined based on the target type required in the context (if any), as described below.
> The target can be
>
> - (1.1) an object or reference being initialized ([dcl.init], [dcl.init.ref], [dcl.init.list]),
> - (1.2) the left side of an assignment,
> - (1.3) **a parameter of a function ([expr.call]),**
> - (1.4) a parameter of a user-defined operator,
> - (1.5) the return value of a function, operator function, or conversion ([stmt.return]),
> - (1.6) an explicit type conversion ([expr.type.conv], [expr.static.cast], [expr.cast]), or
> - (1.7) a non-type template-parameter ([temp.arg.nontype]).

But in this situation, the type of the target (the parameter of the function) needs to be determined.  Also note [temp.deduct.funcaddr](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.funcaddr):

> Template arguments can be deduced from the type specified when taking the address of an overload set.
> **If there is a target, the function template's function type and the target type are used as the types of P and A, and the deduction is done as described in [temp.deduct.type].**
> Otherwise, deduction is performed with empty sets of types P and A.

In this case, the template type deduction fails. See [temp.deduct.type](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type):

> In most cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P participate in template argument deduction.
> That is, they may be used to determine the value of a template argument, and template argument deduction fails if the value so determined is not consistent with the values determined elsewhere.
> In certain contexts, however, the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified.
> **If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.**

and

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> [...]
>
> - (5.6) A function parameter for which the associated argument is an overload set ([over.over]), and one or more of the following apply:
>
>   - (5.6.1) more than one function matches the function parameter type (resulting in an ambiguous deduction), or
>   - (5.6.2) no function matches the function parameter type, or
>   - (5.6.3) **the overload set supplied as an argument contains one or more function templates.**
>
> [...]

Comment: I am downvoting because this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @alan could you be more specific, so that i can clarify what you don't understand?  The problem with this type of questions, is to quote the relevant parts of the standard, without quoting too much. The answer that is currently most voted doesn't actually clarify the question from the op since it says in substance that the code should work...

Comment: @alan i've added some clarifiction.  perhaps that addresses your concerns.

Comment: @wearetherobots The main problem with this answer is that it ignores [over.over#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#3) which says: *"The specialization, **if any**, generated by template argument deduction for each function template named is added to the set of selected functions considered."* Note the emphasis one the phrase *"if any"* which is supposed to mean that even if template arg deduction fails(and so a specialization can't be generated), we will only get a hard error if the set doesn't contain any other function. But in this case the set does contain another function...

Comment: ...which can be used. That is, there should not be any hard error since even though the deduction failed, the set is not empty since it contains a non-template function that can be used.

Comment: @user12002570 that's where our understanding differ.  based on https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct#type in order to perform the template argument deduction, the compiler must consider the potential specialisations.

Comment: @user12002570 ... although in this case there is indeed no specialisation of the template function.  So I'm not sure what you meant.  There is only the non-template function and the template function part of the overload set, that need to be considered.

Comment: @wearetherobots Since template argument deduction doesn't happen here there is nothing to add to the set. So the set contains only the non-template function. Which will be used. This is what happens afaik.