# What are the implications of over.over#note-2?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, overload-resolution

Yeah, just what does [over.over#note-2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#note-2) (which I casually stumbled on while reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171988/5825294) answer) mean? I really don't understand.

For context, I copy the text of [over.over#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#2) below:

> If there is no target, all non-template functions named are selected. Otherwise, a non-template function with type F is selected for the function type FT of the target type if F (after possibly applying the function pointer conversion ([[conv.fctptr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.fctptr))) is identical to FT.
>
> [Note 2: That is, the class of which the function is a member is ignored when matching a pointer-to-member-function type. — end note]

So, can anybody show me an example where *"the class of which the function is a member is ignored when matching a pointer-to-member-function type"*?

Comment: Notes in the standard are clarifying or explanatory - they are not normative.

Answer (score 2):

Note that [member functions have regular function types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#general-18) and not some sort of special member function type. For the purpose of [over.over], only the function type matters when selecting an overload and not which class the function belongs to.

In other words

```
template<int>
struct A
{
    void f() {}
    static void g(A*) {}
    void h(this A&) {}
};

struct B : A<0>, A<1>
{
    using A<0>::f;
    using A<0>::g;
    using A<0>::h;
    using A<1>::f;
    using A<1>::g;
    using A<1>::h;
};

void (A<0>::* pf)() = &B::f;  // ambiguous
void (*pg)(A<0>*) = &B::g;    // not ambiguous
void (*ph)(A<0>&) = &B::h;    // not ambiguous
```